# Is it possible to place two forms and save two cookie values in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I'm wondering if it would be possible to place two forms on the same page
and saving their cookie values respectively after clicking submit buttons.

With code below, when I click submit button on the first form, its cookie value is saved successfully but when I click on the second form, second value is saved but the first value is overwritten.

```php
<?php
    setcookie('username[user111]', $_POST['user111'], time()+60);
    setcookie('username[user222]', $_POST['user222'], time()+60);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>name：<?php echo $_POST['user111']; ?></p>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="user111" value="TOM">
<input type="submit" value="close">
</form>

<p>name：<?php echo $_POST['user222']; ?></p>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="user222" value="BOB">
<input type="submit" value="close">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to save both

```
Name:username[user111] Value:BOB
Name:username[user222] Value:TOM
```

If I could save the values respectively, it'd not necessary to use form submit
but if possible I'd like to use PHP instead of JavaScript. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: only the details of one form will submit, not  both

Comment: Do you want to save them at the same time i.e. both forms on one submission or do you just want them to be set independently when a user chooses which one the want to fill in?